# Javascript get last history unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, html, history

Using this code, it cannot provide the last history item correctly, instead it displayed `undefined`:

```
<input type="button" onclick="getHistoryLast()" value="test">
<script>
function getHistoryLast(){
    var x=history.previous;
    alert(x);
}
</script>
```

What is the correct code to retrieve the last history item's URL?

Comment: Hmm, `history.previous` is obsolete in Gecko, not supported in IE, and not part of the W3C spec. Seems like you cannot use it.

Comment: I use onclick ="javascript:history.back()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `document.referrer` to view the last page history instead of using the `history` object.

Also to note that `history.previous` property is not available to web content and is not supported by other browsers and it is obsolete.

You may check these references:

- [Steal Browser History Without JavaScript](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070228/steal-browser-history-without-javascript/)
- [Steal History with javascript](http://www.dicabrio.com/javascript/steal-history.php)

Comment: Isn't really working. http://tool-box.weebly.com/member.html check out the button `test`. alerted empty message.

Comment: So actually, how can i get just the last history?

Comment: @Jamie:- you may try to change `var x=history.previous;` with `var x=document.referrer;` this will give you the URL of the last page the user visited, if they got to the current page by clicking a link

Comment: if it is redirected by `window.location.href`, will `document.referrer` work?

Comment: @Jamie:- I dont think it will work in that case. In that case you may try like this(Although not sure) `$.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});`